# DependencyProperty Update on child property changes

Tags: c#, uwp, dependency-properties

In my UWP app, I have a Object with a List inside like so:

```
public partial class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> MyList{ get; set; }
}
```

Now I want a UserControl with a DependencyProperty of type `Test` in my Page1. It should update a ListView with ItemSoure bound to Test.MyList.

If I add an Item to Test.MyList I want the ListView to refresh and show the new Item, but I haven't figured out how to update a DependencyProperty if only a "child property" changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch to an ObservableCollection, and after you update a property, call `mycollection.Refresh()`

Answer (score 2):

*DependencyProperty* has nothing to do here, for *ListView.ItemsSource* use a collection that implements *INotifyCollectionChanged* - a good example here is mentioned before [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx). Such collection will automatically notify the UI about its changes.

Sample can look like that - in your user control define DP:

```cs
public Test MyData
{
    get { return (Test)GetValue(MyDataProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyDataProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDataProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyData", typeof(Test), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

In xaml - use binding to set it as source for *ListView*:

```xml
<ListView Header="{x:Bind MyData.Name}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyData.MyList}"/>
```

Once you have this, just use it in your page:

```xml
<local:TestControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" MyData="{x:Bind FirstTest}"/>
<local:TestControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" MyData="{x:Bind SecondTest}"/>
```

The when you add/remove element in one of the collections in the behind, it should be updated in the UI. Couple of remarks - I've used here OneTime binding, as for the purpose of this sample it's not needed other way. You may also think of implementing *INotifyPropertyChanged* in your *Test* class to notify UI about changes to other properties.

Working sample you can check at [GitHub](https://github.com/Romasz/UWPSamples/tree/master/DPWithItemCollection).

Comment: ObservableCollection only notifies the UI when an item is added/removed, despite the documentation may give a different vibe. 
You will actually have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on every item of the Collection, if you want to make any kind of modification on them.

Comment: @AndréB That's right, I only referred to the OP's question where he wanted to see the new item added. *INotifyPropertyChanged* will be needed on everything that can change and should be reflected within UI.